# ¿Cómo remover el nombre de un elemento div padre una clase con C# Razor?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

En jQuery se puede obtener el elemento padre de un elemento `div` y remover la clase, una cosa similar a esto:

```
var padre = $("#id_div").parents('li');
var id_padreDIV = padre.attr('id');
$("#" +id_padreDIV).removeClass("estilo_div")
```

En la vista tengo estos elementos:

```
 <li id="li_padre" runat="server" class="estilo_div">
                            <a id="id_div" runat="server" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-exchange"></i>Solicitud</a>
                        </li>
```

En C#, necesito obtener el id=li_padre

Pero al trabajar en MVC y Razor, ¿cómo sería o se traduciría el ejemplo de jQuery en un View usando Razor?

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar una muestra del código que tienes en tu View?

Comment: Solamente necesito un ejemplo de lo que puse, pero en C#

Comment: Vale, es que depende mucho de cómo estés haciendo el render del razor, y si se involucra o no el Model, si tienes un ejemplo de más o menos que es lo que requieres te podría dar una respueta más puntual ;)

Comment: para remover el nombre de una clase en C# se que se hace así:

   @ id_div.Attributes.Add("class", id_div.Attributes["class"].ToString().Replace("estilo_div", ""));

Pero no se obtener el elemento padre, asi como se usa el parents en Jquery y el attr

Comment: @Flxtr, edite la pregunta colocando los elementos a los cuales necesito referenciarlo

Comment: `runat="server"` corresponde a ASP.NET WebForms, y Razor a MVC y por lo que veo en esa sección de código no usas sintaxis de Razor, por lo tanto lo puedes obtener con jQuery así como lo pones en un inicio de tu pregunta ;)